# Why smoothCon gives different estimates of smooths than mgcv?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, smoothing

I am learning gam by myself. I tried to find posts that can help me to finding and understanding smooth functions i.e., basis functions from gam using `mgcv`. From a post I found I can use `smoothCon` to estimate basis functions without explicitly from the model. However when I did so, I observed `smoothCon` and `mgcv$smooth` doesnt match.
Here an reproducible example of what I did:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(1)
x.1=runif(80)
x.2=runif(80)
fx.1=sin(x.1*.2)
fx.2=cos(x.2)
fx=fx.1+fx.2
y=rbinom(80,1,fx/(1+exp(fx)))

gam.m= gam(y~s(x.1,bs="cr",k=4)+s(x.2,bs="cr",k=4), family=binomial, method="REML")
```

Now, I extracted basis functions

```
smooth.mgcv= predict.gam(gam.m,type="lpmatrix")
smooth.x.1= smooth.mgcv[,2:4]  #basis functions of x.1#
```

then from smooth.Con

```
smooth.create=smoothCon(s(x.1,bs='cr',k=4),data=data.frame(x.1=x.1),knots=NULL)
```

, but this two are giving different output. How do this basis functions work?

Answer (score 0):

`smoothCon()` only creates the basis functions for the requested smooth, and by default it doesn't apply identifiability constraints. `gam()` estimates the coefficients for each basis function.

The specific source of the difference here is the most likely due to the first feature; by default `absorb.con` is set to `FALSE` in `smoothCon()`, which means that the constant function (in this case) is in the span of the basis. If you apply the same identifiability constraint that was applied when fitting via `gam()`, the basis functions evaluated at the same data point should match whether you use `"lpmatrix"` in the `predict()` call or `smoothCon()`.

More correctly, you should use `PredictMat()` to evaluate the basis functions at specific locations.

Here's an example using some utilities from my gratia package to make this a little easier

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia") 

# simulate data
df <-  data_sim("eg1", n = 2000, dist = "binary", seed = 42)
m <- gam(y ~ s(x0, bs = "cr") + s(x1, bs = "cr") + s(x2, bs = "cr") + 
             s(x3, bs = "cr"),
         data = df, family = binomial, method = "REML")

# generate data to evaluate the basis functions at
ds <- data_slice(m, x0 = evenly(x0, n = 10))

# create the basis expansion as `gam()` would do it
sm <- smoothCon(s(x0, bs = "cr"), data = df, absorb.cons = TRUE)[[1]]
# evaluate this basis at the 10 evenly spaced values of x0
p1 <- PredictMat(sm, data = ds)

# compute the lp matrix at the same set of points
p2 <- predict(m, newdata = ds, type = "lpmatrix")
# pop off the intercept to aid comparison
p2 <- p2[, -1]

# compare
identical(p1[, 1], unname(p2[, 1]))
```

but extracting the smooth model matrix from the object created by `smoothCon()` also works

Also, don't use `predict.gam()`; this function is an S3 method and you should really only be calling `predict()`.